# Nested interval theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]$ is a subset of $[a_n, b_n]$ , how to proove that $a_m\le b_n$ for any natural numbers $m,n$? I need the exact proof, not because it is $a_1<a_2<...<a_n<..<b_n<..<b_2<b_1$!

Answer (score 0):

If $m \ge n$ then $a_m \le b_m \le b_n$.

If $m \le n$ then $a_m \le a_n \le b_n$.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot this, am> = an, for m> n is easy to prove by induction, etc...